# UV Vertex Question

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm currently tidying up a UV mesh so the texture displays properly. Is there any way of moving more than one vertex at the same time when organising their position? For instance, I would like to move the five highlighted vertices together, but whenever I click and hold the mouse button, they unselect and only one remains highlighted.

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I've been reviewing your mesh and I think the problem is the way you're trying to move the vertices, so why don't you try selecting the vertices (press C and then select them).

[image]

Then press G to move them, instead of holding the mouse button.

[image]

Comment: Yeah, I probably shouldn't have saved that screenshot with Face selection mode selected... But even with Vertex selection, they still don't all move at the same time. Doing it via Edge and Face select does make it a bit easier though.

Comment: Wow that's weird. Can you provide the blend file to take a look?

Comment: I've edited the original post